# Cannot display a certain pic for an admin and a simple user in a chat app

Tags: javascript, php, html, phpmyadmin

Trying to display a different pic for the logged in user if it's an admin or a simple user. Here is my function

```
function isAdminPhotoChange() {
    // check if user is admin or user
    if (isset($_SESSION['user']) && $_SESSION['user']['user_type'] == 'admin') {
        if (file_exists("images/metcircle13.png")) {
            $filename = "$metcircle13.png";
            echo '<img src="images/<?php echo'. $filename.'?>" style="height: 50px;">';
        } else {
            if (isset($_SESSION['user']) && $_SESSION['user']['user_type'] == 'user') {
                $filename = "user_profile.jpg";
                echo '<img src="images/<?php echo'. $filename.'?>" style="height: 50px;">';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the call in another php file

```
<?php
include("functions.php");

$comm = mysqli_query($db, "select name,comment,post_time from comments");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($comm)){

    $name=$row['name'];
    $comment=$row['comment'];
    $time=$row['post_time'];
}

?>
<div class="sxolion">
<strong style="margin: 3px; color: #000; text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #3d5c5c;"><?php isAdminPhotoChange(); ?><br><p style="margin: 4px;"><?=$name?></p></strong><p style="margin: 3px;"><?=$comment?></p><span class="time"><br><p style="margin: 4px;"><?=date("j/m/Y g:i:sa", strtotime($time))?></p></span>
```

Thank You!

Comment: This `$filename = "$metcircle13.png";` doesn't look right

Comment: You can't have php tags inside php tags

Comment: `echo "<img src='images/$filename' style='height: 50px;'>";` TWICE

Comment: You need to change `if(file_exists("images/metcircle13.png")){` to `if(file_exists("images/$metcircle13.png")){`.

Comment: thanks those are realy helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the nicest way possible, there was an awful lot of logic/syntax errors in your isAdminPhotoChange() function that have been mentioned in the comments, and some more - though none that would of thrown an error.

Here's my attempt at fixing just that function, as the rest appears OK:

```
function isAdminPhotoChange()
{
    // ENSURE SESSION HAS STARTED
    if(session_status() === PHP_SESSION_NONE)
    {
        session_start();
    }

    $admin_img = "images/metcircle13.png";
    $user_img = "images/user_profile.jpg";

    // IS ADMIN
    if (isset($_SESSION['user']) && $_SESSION['user']['user_type'] == 'admin' && file_exists($admin_img))
    {
        echo '<img src="'.$admin_img.'" style="height: 50px;">';
    }
    // IS USER
    else if (isset($_SESSION['user']) && $_SESSION['user']['user_type'] == 'user' && file_exists($user_img))
    {
        echo '<img src="'.$user_img.'" style="height: 50px;">';
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably a typo - Admin image source would be `images/images/metcircle13.png`

Comment: Thanks. Yes that is true, I'm trying to learn php but I'm a bad student :D Well it works ! Thank you. The problem is that when I'm logging in as a different user it changes the images. Is not for the account! Anyway thanks

Comment: @L-DracWarThorn Are you sure you have used `session_start();` and that there are actually values inside the `$_SESSION` variable? ... I edited my code above to ensure the session has started.